# What would be a minimum system/browsers version to run a simple website?

Tags: browser, system, compatibility, requirements

I got this job which I have to create a promotional website for a prefecture and they are asking me to list the minimum system requirements a user must fulfill to access this website. I am not sure on how to make this list. The website will have two versions: one very simple for older browsers and computers, and another one responsive. The idea is to maintain everything very simple, without any animation or something that would be difficult to run on older browsers.

What do you guys think would be a safe way to describe the minimum system/browsers version for using a website like this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most web development companies set a minimum level of browser support, not so much system specifications.  My development company specifies the most recent two versions of Internet Explorer, FireFox, Safari and Chrome.  If they need to support older browsers, I would set the minimum to IE8 and maybe 10 previous versions of FireFox, Chrome and Safari.

Also, you should use something like the HTML5 boilerplate and feature detection in the site.  That way you can build one website that satisfies all of the requirements. Building two separate sites becomes a nightmare when it comes to future updates.

Comment: Thank you Chris for the quick reply. They need the specifications for the OS because it will be used for all kind of users and maybe some of them are still using old computers. Since we have some freedom to decide which system will be idea for our project, I guess Windows 7 or newer and Mac OS X 10.6 or newer will be ok. What do you think?

Comment: Usually the computer itself isn't the inhibiting factor, it's the browser itself.  An old computer running the latest version of Chrome will still run everything properly, it'll probably just do it a bit slower.  But sure, I think if you need to set an arbitrary minimum, go with Win7 and OSX 10.6.  With both Microsoft and Apple providing free OS upgrades these days I'd think most people will be above those as well.